# java -version в cmd

Tags: java

Возник такой вопрос, почему командная строка использует версию `1.8`, и как ее поменять? Я понимаю, что из-за того, что наша `java` до 8-го пакета включительно ставилась удачно `exe` файлом, и все необходимые настройки производились сами. Но теперь я хочу допустим компилировать `java` файлы 12-ой версией через ком. строку, а там используются старая 8-ая. В гугле я нашел такое решение - необходимо указать верный путь в `JAVA_HOME`, т.е. 12ую версию `jdk`, и тут уже есть непонятности, где-то я видел что нужно указывать именно файл `java.exe` из `bin`, а где-то говорят нужно там указывать корень папки `jdk-12.0.1`. Так же пишут надо добавить путь в переменную `Path`, и там нужна папка `bin`, но все это не помогает.

Comment: Переменная окружения `JAVA_HOME` должна указывать на корень соответствующего каталога JDK. А в `PATH` нужно добавить `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Я в такой ситуации просто удалил `1.8`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я долго не понимал почему Ваш вариант не работает, да и тем более я так делал, только вот вместо `%JAVA_HOME%` я использовал полный путь, а по сути я так понимаю это одинаковая запись, в итоге все заработало после того, как я поднял `%JAVA_HOME%` на первое место, подскажите почему именно так?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия у меня была такая идея, но решил что 8-ая версия может каким-то образом еще пригодится

Comment: @VladZherihov ну если понадобится, я опять установлю. То есть вы подняли путь на первое место? У меня просто тоже этот способ не работал.

Comment: Потому что поиск идёт в том порядке, в котором пути заданы в PATH, и останавливается после первого подходящего варианта.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия да, при чем я знаю, что поиск работает так, как описал Sergey, но я не понимаю на что там могло наткнуться, ведь другие пути относятся не к `java`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, вот как Влад пишет, на что могло наткнуться, если другие пути относятся не к `java`?

Comment: Например Oracle JRE 8 в самое начало `PATH` прописывает `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. Ещё я слышал о том, что некоторые JRE засовывают java.exe в `%SystemRoot%\System32`. Надо разбираться с вашим конкретным случаем. У меня замена значения `JAVA_HOME` прекрасно работает.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия у меня на самом деле беда была из-за `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`, я не подумал, что эта переменная повлияет на поиск